# php gethostbyname() function

Tags: php

Using `gethostbyname()` does not always return an IP address. Instead it returns the same hostname back again. What are the reasons for this ? At first I thought that it was a fake hostname. Then using it in a function that is trying to catch some bots it caught baidu as using a fake hostname, which as I tested was a false.

example:

```
echo gethostbyname('baiduspider-123-125-71-12.crawl.baidu.com');
```

returns

```
baiduspider-123-125-71-12.crawl.baidu.com
```

but

```
echo gethostbyname('201-35-178-134.cslce701.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br');
```

returns

```
201.35.178.134
```

Any help in understanding this better appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:
Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.

If it doesn't find the domain or there is no corresponding A-Record it returns the unmodified hostname.

In your example, Baidu has not set up an A-Record for their bots, in Linux the `host` command prints that:

```
Host baiduspider-123-125-71-12.crawl.baidu.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: exactly what i get in console but also on online services. And the missing A-Record is also another thought I made. But how could in this case get the IP to do a reverse DNS check ? thanks

Comment: You can only do it in one direction (I made this experience too when I wrote a bot blocking system). You need to differentiate between bots and for example for Baidu you can only do a backwards check, you can't resolve the Hostname back. There is nothing you can do about that. You can only match the RDNS against some regex that tries to find out if it is at least *.baidu.com. If somebody fakes this, it is not possible to distinguish between him and a legit Baidu bot if you don't want to operate with netblocks. But that isn't good practice.

Comment: I was afraid I would hear all that and, that unfortunately I will have to make lists for special cases of bots. Yeah this is a bad-bot detection mechanism. It is easy to check that ending part of the hostname to match `.baidu.com` as I do as a first-fast-check for fake googlebot already. At least I can log such cases of bots that do not resolve to an IP and later add exclusions. Thanks again.